# How to show $\{x_1 + I, ..., x_n + I\}$ is algebraically independent.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be a field and let $R = k[x_1, ...., x_n]/I$ where the $x$'s are variables. I am supposed to show that $x_1 + I, ..., x_n + I$ are algebraically independent. But if I take any polynomial $F$ in $I$, then 
$$
F(x_1, ..., x_n) \in I. 
$$ 
So that $F(x_1 + I , ...., x_n + I )$ is $0$ in $R$, which seems to imply that it is algebraically dependent.
Not sure what I am missing.. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: You are right, this depends on $I$.

Comment: It's surely a typo. Most likely, the intended exercise was to show that those elements are algebraically _dependent_ (which you've shown).